# How to monitor system audio with js

Tags: javascript, html

Using code below I'm able to generate array with frequences based on audio element (which "plays" audio from file), but what I want to do is to generate this array for system audio - the thing that speakers play for example for the sound that is played by another program.

```
AUDIO=document.getElementById("myHtmlAudioElement");
audioCtx = new AudioContext();
analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(AUDIO);
source.connect(analyser);
source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
function getData(){
    return new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
}
```

Comment: This is not really feasible in a production environment. *Some* PCs allow you to select the sound card/stereo mix as a microphone input (on modern Windows the option to enable this is hidden behind quite a few menus), which would potentially enable you to access it via `navigator.mediaDevices` and use the stream with an analyser node. I haven't tested this so no promises, and again, I'm not sure how useful it would really be.

Comment: This did the trick for me. It's not perfect one but it works.